# Hibernate n+1 problem with collection property of child entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am having the n+1 problem with getting the collection of child entities. Let me share the model it will be easier to understand. These are comments and replies both having collection of attachments.
This is abstract Comment class having @ElementCollection of attachments:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Comment {

    @Id
    @UuidGenerator
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.VARCHAR)
    private UUID id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column(name = "attachment")
    private Set<String> attachments;
```

TopLevelComment class which models high level comment:

```
@Entity
public class TopLevelComment extends Comment {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentComment", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Set<Reply> replies = new HashSet<>();
```

Reply class which models the reply to TopLevelComment:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Reply extends Comment {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_comment_id")
    private Comment parentComment;
}
```

Now I use this service method to get the TopLevelComments with selected Ids, and I want to fetch also the replies and the attachments for both levels:

```
public List<CommentDto> getCommentsForObject(UUID commentedObjectId) {
    return topLevelCommentRepository.getAllByIdIn(ids)
            .stream()
            .map(c -> mapper.map(c, CommentDto.class))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(CommentDto::getCreated))
            .toList();
}
```

And this is a custom @Query that I use to fetch it from database:

```
@Query("""
       SELECT c
       from TopLevelComment c
       left join fetch c.replies
       left join fetch c.attachments
       left join fetch c.mentions
       WHERE c.id in :ids
       """)
List<TopLevelComment> getAllByIdIn(List<UUID> ids);
```

Now in the database I do have one comment which has 2 replies. If I use the following method I got such queries executed by Hibernate:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        t1_0.id,
        a1_0.comment_id,
        a1_0.attachment,
        t1_0.commented_object_id,
        r1_0.parent_comment_id,
        r1_0.id,
        r1_0.commented_object_id,
    from
        top_level_comment t1_0 
    left join
        reply r1_0 
            on t1_0.id=r1_0.parent_comment_id 
    left join
        comment_attachments a1_0 
            on t1_0.id=a1_0.comment_id 
    where
        t1_0.id in(?)
Hibernate: 
    select
        a1_0.comment_id,
        a1_0.attachment 
    from
        comment_attachments a1_0 
    where
        a1_0.comment_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        a1_0.comment_id,
        a1_0.attachment 
    from
        comment_attachments a1_0 
    where
        a1_0.comment_id=?
```

So it generates one query in which it fetches correctly replies and attachments for the TopLevelCommnent but then it does n queries to fetch attachments for each n replies that I have :(

```
@Query("""
       SELECT c
       from TopLevelComment c
       left join fetch c.replies r
       left join fetch c.attachments
       left join fetch c.mentions
       left join fetch r.attachments
       WHERE c.id in :ids
       """)
List<TopLevelComment> getAllByIdIn(List<UUID> ids);
```

Such query also gives the same number of n+1 queries :(

So the question is the following: is it even feasible to somehow avoid the n+1?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: In the database, if you have only 1 top-level-comment only, no mentions, no reply but this one comment has 200 attachments, then you will get 200 times the same top-level-comment. Thats how leftjoin works.